# gnome-terminal printing unnecessary logging

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04. I am running a python code where at some point  I need to launch a new terminal and run a piece of code in it. I use `gnome-terminal` command to do so. But when I run this command I see unnecessary loggings being printed like,

```
 gnome-terminal
# _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
# _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
# watch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
# unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (active: 0, establishing: 1)
# watch_established: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0)
```

Can someone tell me how can I stop printing this logging?

Comment: This looks to be a question better suited for AskUbuntu or SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

You can add -q after gnome-terminal to output silently
-q, --quiet